# How do I access a laptop's webcam in TideSDK?

Tags: webcam, tidesdk

I don't want to use a Flash polyfill. I want it to be purely made in HTML5/JavaScript/TideSDK. Is there an API for it? Or any possible way to access it without resorting to flash usage?

TideSDK v1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to access it yet via the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I'll be looking forward to when it is finally implemented.

Answer (score 0):

can you please file a new feature request here: https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/issues

This is the list of proposed features and open bugs in tidesdk we are consolidating it at single place.

thanks,